# How can I use (complex) interactable, scalable SVG graphics as faces in a-frame a-boxes?

Tags: svg, aframe

I have created a HTML page using a-frame which shows a table in front of a chalkboard.

On the table will be several `a-box`es, which will need different `svg`s as texture on the top and the sides.

How can I have different `svg`s for each face, ensure that they are scaled as vector graphic and not pixel-scaled and events work for the elements in the `svg`s?

The target is that I have an e.g. 1,6m*1m table, can draw in the svg in SI units and ensure that e.g. pencil strokes still look like they looked before and do not get blurred or whatever due to pixel scaling and anti aliasing and the like.

My first example right now looks this way in code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="tp://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.4.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://supereggbert.github.io/aframe-htmlembed-component/dist/build.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a-scene>
    <a-plane id="table" position="-0.8 1.2 -0.5" rotation="-90 0 0" width="1.6" height="0.1" depth="1.0" htmlembed>
      <svg height="100%" width=" 100%" viewbox="0 0 400 250" style="background-color: lightgray"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <symbol id="OpenSwitch" class="OpenSwitch">
          <polyline class="OpenSwitchInput SwitchInput Input" points="0,1 1,1 2,0" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.25" />
          <polyline class="OpenSwitchOutput SwitchOutput Output" points="2,1 3,1" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.25" />
        </symbol>
        <symbol id="ClosedSwitch" class="ClosedSwitch">
          <polyline class="ClosedSwitchInput SwitchInput Input" points="0,1 1,1 2,1" stroke="black"
            stroke-width="0.25" />
          <polyline class="ClosedSwitchOutput SwitchOutput Output" points="2,1 3,1" stroke="black"
            stroke-width="0.25" />
        </symbol>
        <use href="#OpenSwitch" x="1" y="0" />
        <use href="#ClosedSwitch" x="3" y="0" />
      </svg>
    </a-plane>
  </a-scene>
</body>

</html>
```

- via A-Frame in browser: [image: via A-Frame in browser]
- just SVG in browser: [image: Just SVG in browser]